# SSIS package to transfer data from MySQL to SQLServer 2008 on a daily basis

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis

I require to transfer data from MySQL database to SQL Server 20078 database. I have been provided with an option to read the data from CSV file and out it into SQL Server. This means that I will have a single CSV for each table into which data needs to be transferred placed on the FTP on a daily basis. I need to copy this CSV to my server machine and then read it and insert the data into SQL Server database. I am successful in doing this, however the files are pretty large (in order of 100s of MB) which takes a lot of time in reading the files from the FTP. So I was looking at some other option which brought me to thinking regarding SSIS.

However I am clueless as to how to migrate data from MySQL database to SQL Server database using SSIS. Can someone please direct me to a proper sequential process which would help me do this?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835445/mysql-to-sql-server-transferring-data) question (and the answers) on SO might help you on your way.

Comment: SQL Server 20078 isn't set to drop for at least another 65 years or so...

Answer (score 0):

Check this pdf file.

http://karthikeyananbarasan.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/sql-server-integration-services-ssis-step-by-step-sample-chapters.pdf

FTP Task:

http://www.cozyroc.com/script/get-ftp-file-list-task